# Native steam games don't launch (vulkan shaders don't work)

Tags: apt, nvidia, updates, steam, vulkan

Hello i have kubutnu 21.10
this happened after the update from 21.04 to 21.10

i have noticed that when i run native linux steam games they don't work, i'm suspecting that there is a problem with vulkan, but when i launch a non steam game it basically skips the processing vulkan shaders and launches the game. I remember when i launcher rocket league it used tot ake a long time to process vulkan shaders now it just doesen't do that. csgo and tf2 don't launch at all.

I hope there is a way to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

edit: portal 2 works fine with no problems

Answer (score 2):

That package, `vulkan-utils` [does not exist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=hirsute&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=vulkan-utils) in any of the supported release.

You probably want `vulkan-tools` instead, which is in the repositories, and ...

> Description-en: Miscellaneous Vulkan utilities  This package provides
> utilities for Vulkan, including vulkaninfo.

Comment: thanks for the help, but i already had that package my problem sis that vulkan shaders don't work when launching a steam game or using goverlay to i thought that vulkan-utils was the problem, i will delete this question and refraze it