# Steam doesn't work on Ubuntu 20.04.3 with proprietary drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, steam, lts

I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.3, and checked the box to install proprietary nvidia drivers. Steam doesn't launch after that. When I do another fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.3 without checking the box for proprietary things -- Steam works fine. What is the problem with that and how to solve it? I thought it was OK to use open source driver, but Terraria and American Truck Simulator lagged a lot on my 1050 Ti

https://pastebin.com/g78KScGT

Comment: That would be a question to ask the good folks at Steam.

Comment: You should've started Steam in terminal when it wasn't opening. That would have produced an error message.

Comment: And this https://askubuntu.com/a/1369567/1210606 is probably relevant too.

Comment: @ChanganAuto

https://pastebin.com/g78KScGT

Comment: Have you disabled Secure Boot in UEFI (or signed the proprietary drivers)? In a nutshell I'm asking here whether you *confirmed* the Nvidia drivers are up and running.

Comment: I don't have UEFI and Secure Boot option. I have BIOS. My motherboard is ASUS P5KPL-AM SE Rev. 2.01G and BIOS version is 0702

Comment: @ChanganAuto, as far as I can understand, they're up and running

https://imgur.com/a/1COvvB0

Comment: Oh no, not necessarily. First of all, unless you're dual-booting with Windows **11** the best you can do is actually disabling Secure Boot. This will save you a lot of headaches. Easy ways to confirm Nvidia drivers are loaded: (1) Open system settings > About or (2) open Nvidia X Server settings.

Comment: I've run `glxinfo | grep -E 'vendor|direct rendering'`, and the output was like this: https://pastebin.com/Dc8W3DBM

also, this told me that the nvidia driver was preinstalled and switched: https://imgur.com/a/1COvvB0

and... my PC isn't supported by Windows 11. I don't have TPM/SecureBoot/UEFI
and I don't have dualboot, I have only SSD with Ubuntu

I did what you said and Nvidia X server and "about" told me I'm using Nvidia driver

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with installing Steam on Ubuntu 15.04+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/614422/problem-with-installing-steam-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Comment: @nobody what should I try of that long thread? I don't understand where to start. And how is this related to me? Steam always worked fine. But not on Ubuntu 20.04.3 now

Answer (score 0):

Actually... This isn't Steam's issue. It's Ubuntu's one. When I do not check the box "install proprietary blah-blah", and then, after successful installing, I just install the nvidia driver, it just works. As it should be. Steam works fine.

But if I do check the box "install proprietary... for graphics, media, Wi-Fi", it doesn't work, and causes lots of crashes if I try to change the drivers.

Ubuntu has to fix that. It's LTS after all.